# R For Loop for converting character to numeric

Tags: r, loops, type-conversion

Using R.
I have a data set that has a "messy" character variable. I need to clean this variable by removing any characters that are not numbers and then converting it to a numeric variable using a for loop.
Here is my for loop.

```
s = messy$SETTLEMENT
n = length(s)
for(i in 1:n){
  // Complete the code that cleans each element of s, s[i], using gsub.
  s = gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", s)
  as.numeric(s)
  
}
```

I am able to clean the variable but s does not return as a numeric variable. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Look at as.numeric

Comment: You almost certainly don't need a loop for this, since R uses vectorization for these types of operations. I don't know that for certain without a [mcve], since we don't know what this vector actually is or what might be going wrong

Comment: With your edit now, it's clear that you didn't actually assign the converted values back anywhere. I'm voting to close this as not reproducible

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readr::parse_number(text_to_be_converted_into_number)`.